# AzureDevOps build pipeline takes too long(25-30 minutes)

Tags: c#, azure-devops, continuous-integration, yaml, devops

I am newbie to the YAMl files and ci/cd , recently i joined the project which  has a ci/cd pipeline, when we run pipeline build takes  approximately 25-30 minute. Application itself is not so huge, i would say it is mid size monolithic application. Bellow you can see the my YAML file

```
trigger:
- development

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Test'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'install'
    workingDir: 'frontend'

- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    workingDir: 'frontend'
    customCommand: 'run build-test'
    
- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'install'
    workingDir: 'admin-frontend'

- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    workingDir: 'admin-frontend'
    customCommand: 'run build-test'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    msbuildArchitecture: 'x64'
    createLogFile: true
    logFileVerbosity: 'diagnostic'


- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
    artifact: 'Web-Project-Test'
```

Also take a look the picture of the particular step times [image]

As you can see the vast amount of time took npm and i guess there would be mechanism of caching, but i do not how to properly change my YAMl file, remove completely npm install step or no?

Comment: if you were to run those npm commands locally, would you expect it to be same, faster or slower?

Comment: Hi NeoXX, Does my answer work? Please check it and kindly let me know the result.

Comment: I am not sur ebecause i have not done anything yet, i was wondering in the case when npm packages would be updated how the  pipiline would behave?

Answer (score 2):

[Pipeline caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops) can help reduce build time by allowing the outputs or downloaded dependencies from one run to be reused in later runs, thereby reducing or avoiding the cost to recreate or redownload the same files again. Thus you could cache `npm modules` by reference to [Node.js/npm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops#nodejsnpm)

```
variables:
  npm_config_cache: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.npm

steps:
- task: Cache@2
  inputs:
    key: 'npm | "$(Agent.OS)" | package-lock.json'
    restoreKeys: |
       npm | "$(Agent.OS)"
    path: $(npm_config_cache)
  displayName: Cache npm

- script: npm ci
```

In addition, [Self-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) give you more control to install dependent software needed for your builds and deployments. Also, machine-level caches and configuration persist from run to run, which can boost speed. Thus you could choose to use [Self-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) in pipelines.

Comment: In this case do i need to delete "npm install" part from my YAML file or not? Or i should leave "npm install" part and just add you suggested  part of the code?

Comment: If you use self-hosted agents, pipeline will find your local installed npm so you don't need this step. If you use npm which is not installed in Microsoft-hosted agents, you need to add this ```npm install``` step in pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same issue, for any variation of the task: Npm@1.

The logs of the task show: "Done in 4.9s", for the npm install command, but the pipeline keeps running for another 3 minutes or so, till it logs: "Finishing: install".

to me it looks like the internal working of the Npm@1 task doesnt properly exit the process when it's finished, and at a certain point (180 seconds) hits a time-out and marks the step as completed.