# My pipeline is taking over 15mins to run, here is my yaml file

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops

Can anyone of you experts, from looking at my yaml why the build is taking 16 mins to run, and when I run it locally in Visual Studio, takes only 2 mins.  Looking at the jobs, the pipeline actually takes less than 4 mins in total but then seems to hang for 12 mins after the tests which come back as all passed.  Am I missing something in the Yaml?

```yaml
 #Sheduling the pipeline 
schedules:
- cron: "0 1 * * *"
  displayName: Daily midnight build
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - releases/*
    exclude:
    - releases/ancient/*
# This trigger block means that the build will execute whenever there is a commit to the develop branch.
trigger:
- master
 
# The pool section specifies which agent pool this build can run on.
pool: Self Hosted Pool VS2019
 
 
# Declare variables to use in this build pipeline. These are optional, the need for variables will depend on the complexity of your build pipelines.
variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'x86'
  buildConfiguration: 'Debug'
  TestProjects: '**/MyProject.csproj'
# enables Semantic Versioning - add new file called GitVersion.yml (see additional steps)
  GitVersion.SemVer: ''

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet --list-sdks '
  inputs:
    command: custom
    custom: ' --info '
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk'
  inputs:
    #packageType: sdk
    version: '3.0.x'
    packageType: runtime

- task: GitVersion@5
  inputs:
    runtime: 'core'
    configFilePath: 'GitVersion.yml'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)' 


- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet build'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    #restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    configuration: $(buildConfiguration)
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Run tests
  continueOnError: true
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '$(TestProjects)'
    publishRunAttachments: false
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --verbosity normal'
```

Further to this, I have managed to speed up the pipeline by replacing the run tests with:

```
script: dotnet test --logger trx --framework netcoreapp3.1
```

However the downside to this is no results are displayed on the dash board, any ideas?

Comment: Never used Github Actions before.  Not sure your logic in using it? Any material that you are referring to?

Comment: @LexLi GitHub Actions and Azure Pipelines are not the same thing.

Comment: @LexLi I'm very familiar with GitHub Actions. The question *isn't about GitHub Actions*, so there was no reason to bring it up -- it's just adding confusion. The YAML posted shows that it's an Azure Pipeline that's using a self-hosted agent. Then your suggestion was "use various tools to analyze the cause of the delay" which is so lacking in specificity that it's not really useful.

Comment: Specfic to Azure Pipeline you have to collect the various logs to assert whether those 12 minutes go, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting/review-logs?view=azure-devops . And if the logs are not that helpful, the only feasible option I think is to log on to your self hosted agent machine (check the log to see which machine in "Self Hosted Pool VS2019" is used) and use tools such as SysInternals.

Comment: try switching to a shared pool - if that will improve the speed, it means it's something specific to your hosted agent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the  [pipeline caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops) mechanism to ***reduce*** the **build time** by allowing the outputs or downloaded dependencies from one run to be reused in later runs, thereby reducing or avoiding the cost to recreate or redownload the same files again. Caching is especially useful in scenarios where the same dependencies are downloaded over and over at the start of each run. This is often a time-consuming process involving hundreds or thousands of network calls.

```
variables:
    YARN_CACHE_FOLDER: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.yarn 
steps:
    - task: Cache@2
    inputs:
        key: '"yarn" | "$(Agent.OS)" | yarn.lock'
        restoreKeys: |
            yarn | "$(Agent.OS)"
        path: $(YARN_CACHE_FOLDER)
        displayName: Cache Yarn packages
    - script: yarn --frozen-lockfile
```

You can use the [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install)  give you more control to install dependent software needed for your builds and deployments. Also, machine-level caches and configuration persist from run to run, which can boost speed.

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67162371/azuredevops-build-pipeline-takes-too-long25-30-minutes)